# VSTO outlook plugin not showing in Microsoft Office Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed one plugin for Microsoft office outlook. I used following tools to develop this plugin.

- Visual studio 2012
- Office Add-ins -> Outlook 2013 Add-in template.

Generated exe using "InstallShield Limited Edition Project"

It is working fine for Office 2013 and 2016. Not working in Office 2007 Outlook.

I have tried to install this in following environments:

- Windows 7 64bit OS and Microsoft Outlook 2013 (**Installation successful and outlook plugin is visible**)
- Windows 7 32bit OS and Microsoft Outlook 2016 (**Installation successful and outlook plugin is visible**)
- Windows7 32bit OS and Microsoft Outlook 2007 (**Installation successful but not outlook plugin is visible**)

Comment: Can't test it now but generally [there should not be a problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-lights-up-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield/) Make sure you use the [correct Ribbon namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee704588(v=office.14).aspx) there are different 
2007 - http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui
201x - http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui
If you don't need to use any Ribbon feature from Office 201x, simply target the 2007, it'l work in all

Comment: Thanks to responding to my post. I have tried to target the Office Add-in to 2007, but I didn't find the option for Office 2007 Add-in template. I have googled for these office 2007 tools but there is no luck. Could you please suggest me how to get this option from vs 2012 project templates? Your suggestion really helps me.

Comment: Can you post the begging of your Ribbon.xml file? (If you use Ribbon Designer, [export it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386297.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have done the changes those you have suggested. But, still I am not able to seeing the plugin in Outlook 2007. I am sharing the sample project that I was doing. If you don't mind, could you please check this source code and let me know where is the mistake in my project?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2jXhVmVhqwHZU4ySVhibkQxTzQ/view?usp=sharing